# How do I change the templates.contact.form.send text in Shopify Dawn theme?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

In the contact form theme file (`sections/contact-form.liquid`) in Dawn theme, there is a Send button text named `templates.contact.form.send`.

How can I change the value of this variable?

The source of the file is at: https://github.com/Shopify/dawn/blob/main/sections/contact-form.liquid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit you theme language file to edit the default value, you can do it in 2 ways:

1. Go to you back-end theme section and choose edit languages.
   [image]

2.Then select templates tab

[image]

3. Scroll down to desired section and edit desired value
   [image]
4. save it

Second approach:

1. navigate to locales folder into you time
2. choose desired language file as per your store language eg en.default.json
   [image]
3. find and replace value according to need and save it
   [image]